# How to make such collapsing card view in collapsing toolbar layout?

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[Before Scrolling the Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHSu.jpg)

[After Scrolling the Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WkKx.jpg)

I am trying to make a card view which can collapse on scrolling as i have shown in pictures.  But In my view cardview is collapsing but its height doesn't change. I have made collapsing toolbar and image but could not make card view collapse with its height changing as per figure shoen.

This is my code for Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Mynew.AppBarOverlay"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_grid_on_24/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/trips" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/var2" />


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="65dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="25dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:maxButtonHeight="70dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/dropmenu"
            app:navigationIconTint="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Mynew.PopupOverlay" />




    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```